# Is it possible to zoom a map out if there are no markers in the area it zoomed into?

Tags: android, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-markers

I haven't been able to find a solution to this one, or find any results that indicate it's even possible. Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

I've got google maps v2 set up to zoom into level 15 of the users location. Easy enough using `CameraPosition`on initial load of the map. I've also got markers loaded in via an `AsyncTask`.

Is there a way to zoom the map out to the closest marker if the map shows no markers when it zooms in on the users location.

In effect, the map would load, zoom to users blue dot. If there are markers shown, nothing happens. If no markers are on the screen then I can zoom to the closest one. Or just zoom out to a high level and tell the user that there were none in their location. Although I prefer to move to the nearest marker; zooming out to a higher level would satisfy me too.

Maybe after the markers have loaded via the Async I can animate the camera to move if need be? I don't really know how to check if markers are present on the screen.

Is there a way to do it? I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the problem of determining if there are any visible markers on the screen. You can do that using the method detailed in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735812/how-can-i-get-the-visible-markers-in-google-maps-v2-in-android).

Once you've decided whether any of the markers you've shown are visible, you'll want to determine which point is closest to the user (if none are visible). This should be reasonably straightforward, as you should have all of the LatLngs for each point and you have the user's LatLng. Then zoom out to show your point(s). This can be done similarly to the below code snippet (the onGlobalLayoutListener is only necessary if you're trying to do this all in onCreate or a similar lifecycle method. If you're sure this will all happen after the map has been laid out, then don't worry about the listener)

```
 if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
                if (noVisibleMarkers) {
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(llbuilder.build(), 100));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Where mapView is a MapView, mMap is a GoogleMap, and llbuilder is a LatLngBounds.Builder containing your user's location and the point(s) you'd like to be contained in the visible section of the map.

Comment: This is all new to me so it looks complicated. I'm not using a MapView, I've got a Map fragment. This doesn't seem to allow getViewTreeObserver(). So the code from the other SO answer is giving me LatLngBounds for the area on screen, then I need to run an if statement to see if the area is empty or not?

Comment: You can get a reference to the MapView inside your MapFragment with the getView() method. As for determining if any of your Markers are in the LatLngBounds, you can use the [contains()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#contains(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) method in LatLngBounds.

Comment: Ok I'm slowly getting to grips with this. I now have an if statement running that says if (mLatLngBounds.contains(markerLocations) { do nothing } else { zoom camera out}. This works well. Now need to understand the whole moving to nearest marker bit.

Comment: Think I did it! This is fantastic. I just set the new camera to zoom to markerLocations and it moved to the visible markers. It's not perfect because it zooms directly onto one of the markers but I can make the zoom level higher, it's just so the user doesn't get a blank map when using the app. +1 and marked as answer. Thank you kindly.